# Constraining Joint angles of a UR5 arm while motion planning in moveit

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS noetic on ubuntu 20.04.3. I have to move my robotic arm towards white coloured object (goal) but while planning the moveit plans a path including weird trajectories and I read somewhere that to avoid this we can constraint the end effector joint angles but I'm not sure how to do this as I'm a beginner to this. Any help would be appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394880/constraining-joint-angles-of-a-ur5-arm-while-motion-planning-in-moveit/) by [Dobit](https://answers.ros.org/users/94619/dobit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This tutorial is close to what you want:

https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html#planning-with-path-constraints

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2022-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dobit](https://answers.ros.org/users/94619/dobit/) on 2022-01-27**:
Thank you for your help. The link was really helpful.